# multiple custom post type category selection search

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets, search

I hope it's clear from the title but let me try to explain it better. Looking at this image should make it clear:

[image: sidebat]

I have custom post type names Product and categories related to it. What I am trying to achieve is sidebar with multiple dropdowns and submit button like in an image above. Plugin will do it or explanation how to code it as well.

Many many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're trying to achieve a filtering mechanism, is that right? - by which users can see a list of products which match the set of criteria they give in the drop-downs.

If that is the case, and although I haven't any experience of doing this precise thing myself, a plugin I use for achieving similar outputs is Views by Toolset.

This provides the ability to do drop-downs, and user-driven parametric search.

You can learn more about it [here](http://wp-types.com/home/views-create-elegant-displays-for-your-content/)

I use this, and their custom fields/post type generator on all my sites now for added flexibility and ease. Their support is top rate too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes I need exact same thing except my budget is tight at the moment as this is not the only thing I'll need but thank you anyways ;)

Comment: @Web inc please in the future try to avoid answers which are based on an external link, especially when it leads to a commercial product that you can't see its code without payment